# Abstract TypeScript property type guarding logic in a typesafe way

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, type-safety, typeguards

I want to create TypeScript functions that safely check if an object's property has a certain type. I created a function called guardKey that confirms the object has a certain key. I use `guardKey` to define two functions that check different property types, `guardString` and `guardNumber`:

```
function hasKey<Data extends Object, Key extends string> (data: Data, key: Key): data is Data & Record<Key, unknown> {
  return key in data
}

function guardKey <Data extends Object, Key extends string> (props: {
  data: Data
  key: Key
}): Data & Record<Key, unknown> {
  if (!hasKey(props.data, props.key)) {
    throw new Error(`There is no ${props.key}`)
  }
  return props.data
}

function guardString (props: {
  data: object
  key: string
}): string {
  const keyed = guardKey({ data: props.data, key: props.key })
  const value = keyed[props.key]
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    const message = `${props.key} is not a string`
    throw new Error(message)
  }
  return value
}

function guardNumber (props: {
  data: object
  key: string
}): number {
  const keyed = guardKey({ data: props.data, key: props.key })
  const value = keyed[props.key]
  if (typeof value !== 'number') {
    const message = `${props.key} is not a number`
    throw new Error(message)
  }
  return value
}
```

`guardString` and `guardNumber` share a lot of code. I want to abstract the logic in these two functions into a shared function that can be used with other native types in a fully type safe way. I tried making a function that takes a custom type guard callback, but TypeScript does not throw errors when the callback logic is incorrect:

```
function guardProperty <T> (props: {
  assert: (value: unknown) => value is T
  data: object
  key: string
  label: string
}): T {
  const keyed = guardKey({ data: props.data, key: props.key })
  const value = keyed[props.key]
  if (!props.assert(value)) {
    const message = `${props.key} is not a ${props.label}`
    throw new Error(message)
  }
  return value
}

const n = guardProperty<number>({
  // This does not actually check for numbers, but there is no error
  assert: (value: unknown): value is number => typeof value === 'string',
  data: { message: 'hello' },
  key: 'message',
  label: 'number'
})
```

I don't have that problem if I use incorrect logic in the versions that separate the logic:

```
function guardNumber (props: {
  data: object
  key: string
}): number {
  const keyed = guardKey({ data: props.data, key: props.key })
  const value = keyed[props.key]
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    const message = `${props.key} is not a number`
    throw new Error(message)
  }
  // This correctly throws the error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'."
  return value 
}
```

How can I abstract the logic in `guardNumber` and `guardString` without decreasing type safety? If custom type guards don't work, what is the type safe way to abstract the logic in those two functions so my code stays DRY?

Comment: See [ms/TS#29980](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29980) for more information: [custom type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) *never* complain if you implement them incorrectly.  (You could implement `hasKey` with `return Math.random()<0.5` and it wouldn't complain).  Their whole purpose is to allow users to write checks the compiler can't see as safe. If you don't want to decrease type safety, don't use custom type guard functions whose implementations you haven't checked yourself.

Comment: Does the previous comment fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I see that type assertions don't work, but I want to know what does work. How can I abstract the logic between guardNumber and guardString into a single function so my code stays DRY? If assertion functions are the way, what is?

Comment: You've used the word "assertions" multiple times in an unconventional way. None of the code here is using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). There are type *predicates* here. Or *custom type guard functions*. Could you edit to use the conventional terminology so as not to distract from the topic you're trying to discuss?  (Also, Is your last comment question missing a "not" somewhere?)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, I updated the question to refer to custom type guards. You are correct, my last comment should have said "If custom type guards are *not* the way, what is?"

Comment: If [ms/TS#57465](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57465) or the like gets merged, then you can use type guard functions without explicit annotations and it will probably just work how you want.  Otherwise, there is no "safe" way to do this since you can't abstract over TS's type guarding functionality. Personally I'd consider just not exposing anything that takes a type guard function, to limit your exposure, such as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wvo3Qw). That works to the extent that you trust your own implementations. Otherwise there's no way to do this now.

Comment: What about [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQjdnN) approach

Comment: @Filly That looks great. I am especially glad it supports guarding syntax like: if (!hasKeyAndIsTypeOf(obj, "a", "string", "number")) { throw new Error('Not a string or number'); }; obj.a; /* typed as string | Number */

I would accept an answer that explained the syntax of your solution.

Comment: I'll write an answer later this day :)